# How to get Bluetooth earbuds (multipoint) battery levels in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, battery

I am having trouble figuring out how to get the battery level of the earbuds independently. I currently have a receiver that triggers when the connected bluetooth device battery level changes or the device turns off.
I can't seem to find any information on how to get individual battery levels from multipoint devices.

I think I might need to use getMethod(), but I cant seem to find the correct method to use.
Maybe I am way off and this may not be possible. I know that the default app for my earbuds current display the levels of both earbuds and the case separately.

Just wondering if anyone could point me in the correct direction. Here is what I currently have.

---

BluetoothReceiver

```
if(intent.getAction().equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.BATTERY_LEVEL_CHANGED")){
    int batteryLevel = intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.BATTERY_LEVEL", -1);
    if(batteryLevel != -1){
        saveCurrentDeviceBatteryLevel(context, deviceJson, batteryLevel);
    }
}else if(intent.getAction().equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED")){
    saveCurrentDeviceConnectionState(context, deviceJson, true);
}else if(intent.getAction().equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED")){
    saveCurrentDeviceConnectionState(context, deviceJson, false);
}
```

---

getMethod()

```
public int getBatteryLevel(String addressString){
    BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(addressString);
    int value;
    try {
        Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("getBatteryLevel");
        value = (int) method.invoke(device);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return value;

}
```